# Best practice for Facebook authorization / action on mobile without plugins

Tags: javascript, android, ios, facebook, cordova

I'm writing an app using Phonegap.

I'd like to give some perks to the user for posting about the app on their wall (or something of the sort) if they wish to do so.

There's a neat [Cordova plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin) which covers Facebook's functionality pretty thoroughly and more importantly it appears that it does so as natively as it can manage.

If a plugin like that is not available however, what is a **high-level overview** for having a user:

1. authorize with FB
2. post something canned on FB
3. ascertain that they have in fact posted what was given to them

I believe there's a way to do these things using Facebook's JavaScript SDK, but I've never seen an app ask me for my username and password (that wasn't the actual Facebook app) and I don't imagine Facebook would be happy with that, so what's the best way to go about that?

Additionally, if I want for a user to log in using Facebook in my app, (think Tinder) what is the data that I should be saving? Facebook login token and device ID? What are the best practices when it comes to using facebook and phone data to identify and store user account information server-side?

Comment: You might want to make that second question (the last paragraph) into its own question--it'll get more attention that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Facebook Login for Android -**

The Facebook SDK for Android provides methods to implement Facebook Login for your app. The SDK provides Facebook Login support for the these common scenarios:

- Your app uses only Facebook Login to authorize people using your app.
- Your app provides two login options: Facebook Login and your own
  login mechanism.
- Your app uses your own login initially and Facebook Login is an
  option to switch on certain social features.

For more - [login-with-facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/v2.0).

***Manually Build a Login Flow -***

The easiest and quickest way to implement Facebook Login is with our official SDKs [for JavaScript](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/getting-started/), [iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-ios/), and [Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook) and we recommend you follow our separate guides for these platforms.

However, if you need to implement browser-based login for an app without using our SDKs, such as in a webview for a native desktop app (for example Windows 8), or a login flow using entirely server-side code, you can build a Login flow for yourself by using browser redirects.

This guide will take you through each step of the login flow and show you how to implement each one without using our SDKs:

- [Checking login status](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.0#checklogin)
- [Logging people in](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.0#login)
- [Confirming identity](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.0#confirm)
- [Storing access tokens and login status](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.0#token)
- [Logging people out](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.0#logout)
- Make direct HTTP requests to [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api) endpoints to retrieve
  and post data.

For more check - [manually-build-a-login-flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.0).

**Pros:**

- No plugin dependency and no uncertainties when new versions of
  Cordova or the Facebook SDK are released.
- Works for all platforms, including platforms for which a version of
  the plugin doesn’t exist.
- Works for both browser-based apps and Cordova apps.

**Cons:**

- Not full-fledged, less out-of-the box features.
- Integration not as tight. For example, no native dialogs, etc.

The logic is integrated together and is available on github as [OpenFB](https://github.com/ccoenraets/OpenFB).

*Sample Example -*

**Login using Facebook:**

```
openFB.login(scope, successHandler, errorHandler);
```

**Get the user’s list of friends:**

```
openFB.api({path: '/me/friends', success: successHandler, error: errorHandler});
```

**Post on the user’s feed:**

```
openFB.api(
    {
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/me/feed',
        params: {
            message: 'Testing the Facebook Graph API'
        },
        success: successHandler,
        error: errorHandler
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you have to use Facebook connect plugin to post something from cordova app, or the other way that I use to post something about my app review is using the URL way. Facebook has feed dialog / share url system to post in facebook. Simply calling it with native browser and correct parameters does the job, facebook takes care about the authorization and posting , I don't need to handle that.

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?
  app_id=145634995501895
  &display=popup
  &href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2F
  &redirect_uri=https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer
```

Found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog) Don't know will it work in inAppBrowser or not, I just call the native browser.

And AFAIK to post from within the app, it has to be the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

[OpenFB](https://github.com/ccoenraets/OpenFB) is even better than the Apache Cordova Plugin. The plugin isn't well maintained. Sometimes it takes months to update to the latest version of Facebook OpenGraph. OpenFB is constantly updated.

Answer (score 0):

You would just use the JavaScript SDK to do this. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.0

You have an option to use standard components or make your own buttons. You can also let users auto-authenticate after granting permissions initially or always press the button etc. The FB docs are easy to follow though.